# Click to activate pen java paint

Tags: java

So I made a paint application in java. However instead of clicking and holding and then dragging to draw something. Instead I want to click to activate my brush/pen and it will draw to where ever I bring the mouse, and then click again to deactivate the brush/pen.

```
public class DrawArea extends JComponent {

private Image image;
private Graphics2D g2;

// Mouse coordinates
private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;    


public DrawArea() {

addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // save coord x,y when mouse is pressed
        oldX = e.getX();
        oldY = e.getY();
    }
});

addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // coord x,y when drag mouse
        currentX = e.getX();
        currentY = e.getY();

        if (g2 != null) {
        // draw oval if g2 context not null
        g2.drawOval(oldX, oldY, 20, 20);
        g2.fillOval(oldX, oldY, 20, 20);

        // refresh draw area to repaint
        repaint();
        // store current coords x,y as olds x,y
        oldX = currentX;
        oldY = currentY;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable that activates when you click, runs until you click again, set the variable to false.  That is what I do.